# SMTP server did not accept the connection or trying to connect to non TLS SMTP server using TLS on cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I get the following error on my cakePHP2.7 project when I move the code to my new server. The code works fine on all my existing servers.
[image: error message]

we are using aws SES as mail service.
We created a sample file as instructed by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-using-smtp-programmatically.html and that also works fine.
Any help is appriciated

code for your reference

```
public $mailarr = array(
    'host'=>'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',        
    'tls'=>true,
    'returnPath'=>'xxx@xxx.com',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('xxx@xxx.com' => 'Alert!'),
    'emailFormat' => 'html',
    'timeout' => 300,   
    );
```

I have tried to add the below as part of my mailarr but the error still persists

```
'context' => array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ),
        )
```

Comment: set tls to false or configure your server

Comment: Tried it already. Still does not work